# Error using case function in sql query with php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to display user ID, username and the count of subscriptions they purchased every year. My database contain two tables namely subscriptions and users as follows:

**users**

| user_id | name | phone_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | xyz | 4567890 |
| 2 | abc | 4578003 |

**subscriptions**

| subc_id | user_id | type | start_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | week | 2019-07-30 17::00:19 |
| 2 | 4 | year | 2020-05-12 22:38:24 |

SQL query i am using in my php code is

```
SELECT subscriptions.user_id, users.name, COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR(subscriptions.start_time) = "2018" AND subscriptions.type = "year" THEN 1 END) AS "2018",COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR(subscriptions.start_time) = "2019" AND subscriptions.type = "year" THEN 1 END) AS "2019",COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR(subscriptions.start_time) = "2020" AND subscriptions.type = "year" THEN 1 END) AS "2020",COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR(subscriptions.start_time) = "2021" AND subscriptions.type = "year" THEN 1 END) AS "2021" FROM subscriptions, users WHERE subscriptions.user_id = users.user_id
```

Problem is it's working fine in my phpmyadmin SQL query interface but when i use it with php mysqli it gives me following error
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '2018' (T_LNUMBER)`

Kindly tell me what is wrong with my code.
My php code is

```
<?php
        $sql = "SELECT subscriptions.user_id, users.name, COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR(subscriptions.start_time) = "2018" AND subscriptions.type = "year" THEN 1 END) AS "2018",COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR(subscriptions.start_time) = "2019" AND subscriptions.type = "year" THEN 1 END) AS "2019",COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR(subscriptions.start_time) = "2020" AND subscriptions.type = "year" THEN 1 END) AS "2020",COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR(subscriptions.start_time) = "2021" AND subscriptions.type = "year" THEN 1 END) AS "2021" FROM subscriptions, users WHERE subscriptions.user_id = users.user_id";
        if ($res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
            if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {
                echo "<table>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th>user_id</th>";
                echo "<th>Name</th>";
                echo "<th>2018</th>";
                echo "<th>2019</th>";
                echo "<th>2020</th>";
                echo "<th>2021</th>";
                echo "<tr>";
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
                {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['user_id'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['2018'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['2019'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['2020'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['2021'] . "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
                echo "<table>";
            }
            else {
                echo "No Records";
            }
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Please show the PHP code, it looks like it's in a string which is in `"`'s

Comment: The first thing wrong with your code is that you don't use [Prepared Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) which is leaving you open to SQL injections.

Comment: if it is not executable then how it would be vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Good point! The ultimate way to protect against SQL injection is `DEL CE3.php` (I am joking, please do not delete your code file).

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that your query works in phpmyadmin neither, although it is syntactically correct, because it is missing a `GROUP BY` clause.

Also, you are not using properly the `"`.
In a line were you use double quotes to assign a string value to a variable like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT subscriptions.user_id, users.name, COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR(subscriptions.start_time) = "2018" ...........";
```

it is wrong to use double quotes again inside to enclose string values and also identifiers like column names.
For string values use single quotes and for identifiers  use backticks.

Also, use proper `JOIN`s with an `ON` clause and not that outdated comma syntax.

Finally add the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT u.user_id, users.name, 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR(s.start_time) = '2018' AND s.type = 'year' THEN 1 END) AS `2018`,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR(s.start_time) = '2019' AND s.type = 'year' THEN 1 END) AS `2019`,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR(s.start_time) = '2020' AND s.type = 'year' THEN 1 END) AS `2020`,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR(s.start_time) = '2021' AND s.type = 'year' THEN 1 END) AS `2021` 
FROM subscriptions s INNER JOIN users u 
ON s.user_id = u.user_id
GROUP BY u.user_id, users.name
```

You could also use a WHERE clause, that would be better for performance and shorten the code,since you are counting only rows with `type = 'year'`:

```
SELECT u.user_id, users.name, 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR(s.start_time) = '2018' THEN 1 END) AS `2018`,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR(s.start_time) = '2019' THEN 1 END) AS `2019`,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR(s.start_time) = '2020' THEN 1 END) AS `2020`,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR(s.start_time) = '2021' THEN 1 END) AS `2021` 
FROM subscriptions s INNER JOIN users u 
ON s.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE s.type = 'year'
GROUP BY u.user_id, users.name
```

There is another way to write this query if you take advantage of MySql's evaluation of Boolean expressions to 1 for `true` and 0 for `false`, with `SUM()` instead of `COUNT()`:

```
SELECT u.user_id, users.name, 
       SUM(YEAR(s.start_time) = '2018') AS `2018`,
       SUM(YEAR(s.start_time) = '2019') AS `2019`,
       SUM(YEAR(s.start_time) = '2020') AS `2020`,
       SUM(YEAR(s.start_time) = '2021') AS `2021` 
FROM subscriptions s INNER JOIN users u 
ON s.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE s.type = 'year'
GROUP BY u.user_id, users.name
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I am new to sql and i had no idea about different between using double quotes and single quotes. Thanks!

Comment: @AyeshaJaved if this answer solved your problem consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark.